# Replacing text with space using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file called Gemfile. One of the lines in this file is this:

```
gem 'my-platform', git: 'git@github.com:me/platform-engine.git'
```

and I want to replace it with this:

```
gem 'my-platform', git: 'git@github.com:me/platform-engine.git', branch:'issue-2'
```

For that I have used this command:

```
sed -i s#platform-engine.git\'#platform-engine.git\', branch:\'issue-2\'#g Gemfile
```

but I get this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me you that just want to append some text to the end of the line. If so, use `$` to refer to end of line and do this replacement:

```
sed -i.bak "/platform-engine.git/s/$/, branch:'issue-2'/" Gemfile
```

This adds the given text to the end of the line containing `platform-engine.git`. Note there is no need to use `/g` because you just want to do the replacement once per line.

Note also it is a good practice to create a backup file, just in case!

---

In case you needed to use single quotes by any meaning, use this escaping strategy:

```
sed 's/'\''//'
       ^^^^
       just to match as single quote!
```

Test:

```
$ echo "he'llo" | sed 's/'\''//'
hello
```

Otherwise you get the error you mentioned: "sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape  `'` if you put the pattern inside double quotes.

```
sed "s~platform-engine.git'~platform-engine.git', branch:'issue-2'~g" file
```

OR

```
$ sed "s~platform-engine.git'~&, branch:'issue-2'~g" file
gem 'my-platform', git: 'git@github.com:me/platform-engine.git', branch:'issue-2'
```

`&` refers to the matched characters.